Encryption/decryption issue when working with files (other than .txt) using Node Forge
Been trying split up files into chunks for performance, then encrypt and decrypt/reassemble upon receipt on the other end (going from browser to SignalR hub to another browser client).
I've had success when using a variety of text files - they get encrypted, split, decrypted and put back together into a blob that can be downloaded and read.
After trying an image file though, I've noticed the final product ends up larger than the original (222kb original, 333kb decrypted)..
I'm guessing this is some kind of encoding difference or that the file isn't being truly read as a binary, I was looking at the docs for Forge and seems like Forge.Byte is considered a number, where as Forge.Bytes is considered a string but not sure if this is a red herring.
Below is an example of the current code, I've switched around a few things like encoding and the return types to try and resolve this but a little stuck - I think I found one SO question that was slightly relevant but literally just mentioned using cipher.output.getBytes() rather than .toHex(). Left some comments in there so you can see some of the stuff I'd tried. I had considered moving to Crypto instead of Forge but feel like that should be the last resort so hopefully someone can assist so I don't need to!
The file splitting process:

async processFile(file: File, decryptedKey: string, iv: string, 
    recipientId: string, isDMS: boolean, messageId: string) {
    const chunkSize = 1024; 
    const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    let startByte = 0;
    var fileId = uuidv4();
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalChunks; i++) {
      const endByte = Math.min(startByte + chunkSize, file.size);
      const chunk = file.slice(startByte, endByte);
      this.cryptoService.encryptChunkUsingAES(decryptedKey, iv, chunk).subscribe(
        encryptedChunk => {
         // Code omitted for brevity
    })

Note: I was originally doing this when calling the encryptChunkUsingAES method, which I read was a way to work with 'bytes' in typescript but that also had the same result:

this.cryptoService.encryptChunkUsingAES(decryptedKey, iv, new Uint8Array(await chunk.arrayBuffer()))

The encryption/decryption process:

encryptChunkUsingAES(key: string, iv: string, chunk: Blob): Observable<Forge.Base64> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      var data = chunk.arrayBuffer().then(ab => {
        var cipher = Forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(key);
        cipher.start(iv);
        cipher.update(Forge.util.createBuffer(ab, 'raw'));
        cipher.finish();
        var encrypted = Forge.util.encode64(cipher.output.getBytes()); // was originally cipher.output.getBytes()
        observer.next(encrypted);
      })
    })
  }

  public decryptChunkUsingAES(key: string, iv: string, chunk: Forge.Bytes): Observable<Forge.Bytes> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      var data = Forge.util.decode64(chunk) // Forge.util.hexToBytes(chunk);
      var cipher = Forge.rc2.createDecryptionCipher(key);
      cipher.start(iv);
      cipher.update(Forge.util.createBuffer(data, 'raw'));
      cipher.finish();
      var decrypted = cipher.output;
      console.log(decrypted)
      observer.next(decrypted.getBytes()); // .toString();
    });
  }

